# Variable range vector selectors in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have two queries:

```
messages_total{fqdn=~"$fqdn"}
```

and

```
delta(some_updates{env="prod"}[10m])*100
```

This is what they produce:

[image]

First one is green graph, and second is orange. Now what I want to do is somehow get this yellow parts that I miss in orange graph. Basically - I need variable range selector here - if the delta value is eg. 100, then select 5m, if it is 1000 then select 500m back etc.

Data points are 100, 200, 201, 202, 202, 202 (as gauge), so when you hit delta 200-100=100 use interval of 10min.

Is this possible in Prometheus? Maybe there is some other way to do similar thing?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, why not use a small selector for every value?

Comment: If I use smaller selector, I would get only peaks at that specific times. I need this for alerting, since I found correlation between this 2 graphs. Then I could specify if green > orange more than 10 min - alert.